# Standard library logging plus loguru

Tags: python, logging

Let's say I'm setting up a script or library that has a few dependencies which use Python's standard library `logging` module but I want to use `loguru` to capture all logs. My first naive attempt was a complete failure, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

To test I have two files

`main.py`:

```
from loguru import logger

from base_log import test_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.debug("In main")
    test_func()
```

and `base_log.py`:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def test_func():
    logger.warning("In test_func")
```

If I run `main.py` (i.e. `python main.py`) then I get the following output:

```
2020-12-16 10:57:48.269 | DEBUG    | __main__:<module>:6 - In main
In test_func
```

When I expect:

```
2020-12-16 11:01:34.408 | DEBUG    | __main__:<module>:6 - In main
2020-12-16 11:01:34.408 | WARNING  | base_log:test_func:9 - In test_func
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a custom handler to intercept standard logging messages toward your Loguru sinks as documented [here](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#entirely-compatible-with-standard-logging).

`main.py` will then look something like this:

```
import logging

from loguru import logger

from base_log import test_func


class InterceptHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            level = logger.level(record.levelname).name
        except ValueError:
            level = record.levelno

        frame, depth = logging.currentframe(), 2
        while frame.f_code.co_filename == logging.__file__:
            frame = frame.f_back
            depth += 1

        logger.opt(depth=depth, exception=record.exc_info).log(
            level, record.getMessage()
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(handlers=[InterceptHandler()], level=0)
    logger.debug("In main")
    test_func()
```

Output:

```
2020-12-16 22:15:55.337 | DEBUG    | __main__:<module>:26 - In main
2020-12-16 22:15:55.337 | WARNING  | base_log:test_func:7 - In test_func
```

This should work for all well-behaved libraries that do not add any handlers other than NullHandler to the libraries' loggers. The rest may need [extra work.](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru/issues/247)